# char(32) data as primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, key

(NOT a duplicate of [Char(4) as Primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750727/char4-as-primary-key) or whatsoever.)

I am designing SQL Server tables for my project. I have two tables so far: `Data` and `Ref`.

`Data` structure:

```
DataID    SomeData      SomeOtherData          RefID
```

`Ref` structure:

```
RefID     UniqueData    AlmostNeverUsedData
```

UniqueData contains unique `char(32)` values and is involved in every single query on `Data`.
AlmostNeverUsedData is needed on ~5% of these queries.

I know using a non-data, auto-incrementing `int` field as the primary key is *almost* always better, especially regarding `JOIN` performances. But in *this* case, using UniqueData as `Ref`'s primary key would allow me to **avoid** using a `JOIN` 95% of the time, since all of the data I need would already be on `Data`.

Do the remaining 5% justify using an auto-incrementing `int`, increasing the queries' (and therefore the application logic's) complexity?

Comment: My instinct would say YES, A join on a INT shouldn't be that much faster. But to get a 100% clear answer you need tests.

Comment: Will you ever have to change `UniqueData`?

Comment: @beny23: Sometimes. Is that a problem? I think SQL Server can be configured to automatically rename all corresponding foreign keys (cascade) if a primary key is renamed, which is exactly what I need.

Comment: If your primary key is also the **clustered key** (which it is, by default) - then a `CHAR(32)` is a horribly bad choice - just because it's **8 times larger** than an `INT`, and it will be replicated into each and every single non-clustered index on that table, too, it'll just **waste tons** of disk space for nothing. A good clustering key should be **as small as possible** - 4 bytes is fine, 8 bytes so-so - anything more is really really bad for performance and space

Comment: How much will it impair the performances? "Bad" is not enough of an answer. Always having to use `JOIN` for something so trivial is also considered "bad" by my users (yes, they do know a bit of SQL — and intend to make use of it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test both structures. It's not hard.

Declare Ref.UniqueData as `primary key nonclustered`, and set its foreign key reference to `on update cascade`. Load it with several million rows of data, and measure performance. (Load it with more data than you predict you'll have in five years.)

From the relational point of view, there's nothing wrong with having a primary key that's 32 bytes long. And from the relational point of view, there's nothing wrong with updating a primary key value. In the relational model, all values are updatable, and "compensating referential actions" (cascading updates and deletes) are part of the model, too.

From the SQL point of view, there's nothing wrong with having a primary key that's 32 bytes long. SQL also allows updating key values, and SQL supports cascading updates and deletes.

From the SQL Server point of view, there's nothing wrong with having a primary key that's 32 bytes long. SQL Server supports updating key values, and SQL Server supports cascading updates and deletes. Just don't make it a clustered primary key.

When I designed the production database at my previous job, I built two databases--one designed around surrogate keys, and one designed around natural keys. I wrote two sets of queries that I expected to be frequently used. They included some select, insert, update, and delete statements. There were many dozens of these. The two sets were functionally identical. (I think I originally used PostgreSQL 8.4. PostgreSQL doesn't implement clustered keys.)

I ran the test queries against each database. If memory serves, about 80% of the queries were faster using natural keys. In some cases, individual SELECT statements were 35 to 40 times faster. When queries using natural keys were slower, they weren't very much slower, and they were still plenty fast enough for the users. (I've written about these tests several times on SO and on DBA.stackexchange.com.)

I found a tipping point, where the performance of surrogate keys started beating the performance of natural keys. But by my estimates, we wouldn't hit that tipping point for 30 years. And there were plenty of tuning options and hardware improvements that made it unlikely that we'd *ever* need to use surrogate keys, even if PostgreSQL development stopped altogether.

Comment: Very nice answer. But I don't understand the "*even if PostgreSQL development stopped altogether*" comment.

Comment: A very practical answer. I would hate doing things "right" without understanding why. Thank you.

Comment: I meant we'd be ok even if there were no version after 8.4. As it is, though, PostgreSQL 9.x has improved features *and* performance in a lot of ways. That company could probably go 40 or 50 years without thinking about switching to surrogate keys.

Comment: After testing it with five times the amount of data accumulated in 20 years (yes, the project will start from imported data), queries are executed in no time. I am glad they got solid hardware to back this up, though I doubt there was actually a risk of losing significant performance.